# Dyes that won’t bind to dna

Tags: biochemistry, dna, protein-binding, purification

I am looking for a dye that won’t bind to DNA. I want to add dye to proteinase K to make is visible when adding to clear buffer liquid samples. I need it to not bind to the DNA so it will be removed during the purification process. Or a dye that will not show up later under fluorescence during processing.

Thank you!

Comment: You may try Crystal violet. This dye is also intercalating with DNA, though it is not fluorescent as far as I know. Disadvantage is that the dye has a low sensitivity.